# What happens if you call a constructor from a destructor?

Tags: php, constructor, destructor, infinite-loop

Calling __construct() function from __destruct(),

```
<?php

public function __construct() {
    echo "Hi";
}

public function __destruct() {
    $this->__construct();
}

?>
```

will it create infinite loop?

Comment: Have you tried it? That's a great way to find out.

Comment: it prints twice, and thats it...but  does it still running in background or not? Is there any way to check that?

Comment: @Craftero Why would it? You are not creating an object (that gets destroyed...), you are just calling a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but this will:

```
class Test {

    public function __construct() {
        echo "Hi";
    }

    public function __destruct() {
         new Test();
    }

}

new Test();
```

Example: http://ideone.com/94XUg

Answer (score 4):

No, it won't. `__construct` is just regular function while called directly instead of using `new ClassName;`

Comment: +1, Ohh but I saw few codes where you are able to call parent's constructer by calling __construct

Comment: @Craftero It's ok since you call parent's method on the already created object, not creating a new one